# Group By data in many to many relation with dates and employees for posts counts

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, transpose

I am trying to evaluate result like this:

```
EmployeeName    March 1 March 2 March 3 March 4 March 5 March 6 March 7
Name 1          15      24      5       2       15      24      5
Name 2          4       2       25      1       4       2       25
Name 3          5       2       5       2       5       2       5
Name 4          15      24      5       2       15      24      5
Name 5          4       2       25      1       4       2       25
Name 6          5       2       5       2       5       2       5
Name 7          15      24      5       2       15      24      5
Name 8          4       2       25      1       4       2       25
Name 9          5       2       5       2       5       2       5
```

I have three tables like:

**articles**

```
+-------------+-----------+----------------------+
| ArticleCode | NoOfWords | ArticleWritingStatus |
+-------------+-----------+----------------------+
| 438341A6D6  |      4526 |                    5 |
| 3A4D94C3CD  |      4526 |                    5 |
| C2C13846B2  |      1254 |                    5 |
| 202298039A  |      2153 |                    5 |
| 442FB09132  |      2153 |                    5 |
| 02B6684883  |      2153 |                    5 |
| 020506CFF2  |      2153 |                    5 |
| F2E46CDF1D  |      2144 |                    5 |
| A8D7F6A287  |      2153 |                    5 |
| 9807F62AA7  |      3212 |                    5 |
| F0F4E382FC  |      3212 |                    5 |
| FA9BB9287C  |      3212 |                    5 |
| 7B6DFBFB50  |      3212 |                    5 |
| 869743DA64  |      3212 |                    5 |
| 5048FFC175  |      2154 |                    5 |
| 3526CBFFAC  |      2541 |                    5 |
| 4EC8E1BBA6  |      2546 |                    5 |
| B0B1568D68  |      7855 |                    5 |
| 0B37BD0EFC  |      1452 |                    5 |
+-------------+-----------+----------------------+
```

**employees**

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| EmployeeCode | EmployeeName        |
+--------------+---------------------+
|           12 | abdullahejaz.globex |
|           13 | abdullahkhan.globex |
|           34 | adam                |
|           16 | adeel               |
|            1 | admin               |
|            8 | ahmadmonu777        |
|           10 | ahsansajjad29       |
|            5 | ajwazainab97        |
|           31 | austin              |
|           26 | basit.abh02         |
|           33 | ben                 |
|           37 | cesar               |
|           36 | danielle            |
|           30 | david               |
|           39 | emily               |
|            3 | genoqasha           |
|           15 | globexweb2          |
|            6 | haseebarshad        |
|           18 | hassanijaz5391      |
|           25 | hussnainazharofc    |
|           17 | huzaifa             |
|           19 | irum                |
|           28 | jameelrashed40      |
|           24 | jamshaid            |
|            9 | jamsheed1480        |
|           32 | jason               |
|           14 | kashif.globex       |
|           27 | knabeel272          |
|            7 | misbahnaz           |
|           22 | moeez               |
|            4 | naimaali749         |
|           38 | ruby                |
|           20 | selina              |
|           35 | seth                |
|           23 | shoaib              |
|           40 | thomas              |
|            2 | usamaawan500        |
|           11 | usmanasghar.globex  |
|           21 | Veenahayat123       |
|           29 | william             |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

**article_employee**  (relational table)

```
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------------------+
| ArticleCode | EmployeeCode | Priority | created_at          |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------------------+
| 0B37BD0EFC  |            3 |        1 | 2021-04-04 05:51:34 |
| B0B1568D68  |            5 |        1 | 2021-04-06 06:10:47 |
| 4EC8E1BBA6  |            6 |        1 | 2021-04-04 06:13:36 |
| 3526CBFFAC  |            7 |        1 | 2021-04-04 08:41:34 |
| 5048FFC175  |            3 |        1 | 2021-04-05 15:31:54 |
| 869743DA64  |            6 |        1 | 2021-04-07 16:33:28 |
| 7B6DFBFB50  |            8 |        1 | 2021-04-07 16:33:58 |
| FA9BB9287C  |            8 |        1 | 2021-04-07 16:34:17 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+---------------------+
```

I have tried this one:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
     '(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(article_employee.`created_at`, "%M %d") = ''',
      DATE_FORMAT(article_employee.`created_at`, '%M %d'),
      ''' THEN CAST(articles.`NoOfWords`/500 AS DECIMAL(11,2)) ELSE 0 END) ''',
       DATE_FORMAT(article_employee.`created_at`, "%M %d"), ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM article_employee
    INNER JOIN `articles` ON articles.ArticleCode = article_employee.ArticleCode
    INNER JOIN `employees` ON employees.EmployeeCode = article_employee.EmployeeCode
WHERE articles.`ArticleWritingStatus` = 5
AND MONTH(article_employee.`created_at`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE());
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT employees.`EmployeeName` AS Employee, ', @sql, ' 
                FROM article_employee
            INNER JOIN `articles` ON articles.ArticleCode = article_employee.ArticleCode
            INNER JOIN `employees` ON employees.EmployeeCode = article_employee.EmployeeCode
        WHERE articles.`ArticleWritingStatus` = 5
        AND MONTH(article_employee.`created_at`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
        GROUP BY Employee'
                   );
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

It gives this result:

```
Employee        April 04    April 05    April 06    April 07
ahmadmonu777    0.00        0.00        0.00        6.42
ajwazainab97    0.00        0.00        15.71       0.00
genoqasha       2.90        0.00        0.00        0.00
haseebarshad    5.09        0.00        0.00        0.00
misbahnaz       5.08        0.00        0.00        0.00
```

While removing group by from the query I will get right record but on group it eliminates the other record of different day for same employee:

```
Employee        April 04    April 05    April 06    April 07
genoqasha       2.90        0.00        0.00        0.00
ajwazainab97    0.00        0.00        15.71       0.00
haseebarshad    5.09        0.00        0.00        0.00
misbahnaz       5.08        0.00        0.00        0.00
genoqasha       0.00        4.31        0.00        0.00
haseebarshad    0.00        0.00        0.00        6.42
ahmadmonu777    0.00        0.00        0.00        6.42
ahmadmonu777    0.00        0.00        0.00        6.42
```

Expected result:

| Employee | April 04 | April 05 | April 06 | April 07 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| enoqasha | 2.90 | 4.31 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 7.21 |
| ajwazainab97 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 15.71 | 0.00 | 15.71 |
| haseebarshad | 5.09 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 6.42 | 7.21 |
| misbahnaz | 5.08 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 11.51 |
| ahmadmonu777 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 12.84 | 12.84 |

If some can help in this very much grateful.

Comment: You kinda forgot to say what you're trying to do - I'm sure we could have a good guess, but it'd be better to be told

Comment: @CaiusJard I want to fetch per day count of an article for a whole month to evaluate the employee performance for that month.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry sorry I couldn't understand what are you telling. Which application code, you are talking about?

Comment: Can you post the expected result according to the example data?

Comment: @FaNo_FN I have updated the expected result. I want total column from the result.

Comment: @FaNo_FN I want one more functionality like all columns of the days of months even it does not exist on the record with 0.00 record.

Answer (score 1):

According the expected result, it looks like I guessed it correctly. Your prepared statement only need to add one little `SUM()` and it will be able to return the correct result.

```
...
 /*just add SUM here ->*/ 'SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(article_employee.`created_at`, "%M %d") = ''',
      DATE_FORMAT(article_employee.`created_at`, '%M %d'),
      ''' THEN CAST(articles.`NoOfWords`/500 AS DECIMAL(11,2)) ELSE 0 END) ''',
       DATE_FORMAT(article_employee.`created_at`, "%M %d"), ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM article_employee
...
```

That's it.

**Update**: Responding to your comment, to get `Total`, you just have to add `SUM(CAST(articles.`NoOfWords`/500 AS DECIMAL(11,2))) AS Total` into your prepared statement. Right after `', @sql,'..` before `FROM` here:

```
...
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT employees.`EmployeeName` AS Employee, ', @sql, ', 
/*add it here*/
SUM(CAST(articles.`NoOfWords`/500 AS DECIMAL(11,2))) AS Total 
                FROM article_employee
         INNER JOIN `articles` ON articles.ArticleCode = article_employee.ArticleCode
         INNER JOIN `employees` ON employees.EmployeeCode = article_employee.EmployeeCode
        WHERE articles.`ArticleWritingStatus` = 5
        AND MONTH(article_employee.`created_at`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
        GROUP BY Employee'
                   );
...
```

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=853aac0f9e6835ba416864dff5dbbdaf)

Comment: I want one more column for total of all records per employee as the last column of the result with name "Total". If any help in this regard will be very great full.

Comment: I have updated the expected result with total column

Comment: Thanks a lot for this update. It is working fine.

Comment: I want one more functionality like all columns of the days of months even it does not exist on the record with 0.00 record.

Comment: You must have a `calendar` table... OR if you're creating date range from query, it's much easier to do if you're using MySQL v8+ OR at least MariaDB 10+.. I suggest a calendar table so you can re-use on other query without having to re-type (or c&p) a date range query.

Comment: please tell me how to do this using query and also how to to do this with calendar table. Please help me out.

Comment: I am using Maria DB 10.3.25.

Comment: I think using **calandar** it should be relational. But how with query?

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=5d49f32e35381184038ac26b08555eb2)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated the query by using CTE for dates columns for month. I am getting an error while there will be records only for one day then it eliminates that day column for example look at [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=21bf8054b3278bbeb4c736d51d093d11). In this you will see all records are from 4th Month and in the result **4th April** Column is eliminated. If I will change the record with different days it works fine.